# Subfield generated by a multiplicative subgroup of the field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field with prime $p$ characteristic and let $X$ be a periodic subgroup of $(F,\, \cdot)$. Let now $K$ be the subfield of $F$ generated by the elements of $X$.

Is it possible to describe $K$ as the set of linear combinations of elements of $X$ by coefficients in $GF(p)$?

In particular is it possible to express an inverse of these linear combinations as another linear combination?

If it is true, can someone give me some clue?

Comment: What if $F$ is the field of rational functions $\mathbb F_p(x)$ and $X = \langle x \rangle$?  Is it possible to express $1/(x+1) \in K$ as a linear combination of $\{x^{r} : r \in \mathbb Z\}$?

Comment: I think $(1+x)\cdot (1-x+x^2-\dots)=1$. Therefore this implies that it is not possible to make such a description? But if I take $X$ to be periodic?

Comment: I've updated the question choosing a periodic $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is yes if $X$ has bounded period, for then $X$ is necessarily finite and cyclic. If $X$ has order $d > 1$, choose $\alpha \in F$ of order $d,$ and let $\alpha$ have minimum polynomial $f(x)$ over $K = {\rm GF}(p).$ Then $f(x)$ divides $x^{d}-1$, and the degree of $f(x)$ is $m,$ the smallest positive integer such that $d$ divides $p^{m}-1$. Now every positive power of $\alpha$ is a $K$-linear combination of $\{1,\alpha,\ldots, \alpha^{m-1} \}$ and any product of $K$-combinations of elements of $X$ is still  a $K$-linear combination of $\{1,\alpha,\ldots, \alpha^{m-1} \}.$  In particular, every element of $X$ is such a combination. Then it is clear that the subfield of $F$ generated by $X$ is contained in $K[\alpha]$, and hence is equal to that field.

Comment: $K[\alpha]$ is isomorphic to the field $K[x]/(f(x))$ which is a field, since $f(x)$ is irreducible over $K$. It is not entirely straightforward to write down inverses, but here goes: take a polynomial $g(x) \in K[x],$ which is not a multiple of $f(x).$ Then $g(\alpha) \neq 0.$ Then we can write $1 = a(x)f(x) + b(x)g(x)$ for some polynomials $a(x),b(x) \in K[x]$, and we obtain $1 = b(\alpha)g(\alpha),$ so $b(\alpha)$ is the inverse of $g(\alpha)$.

Comment: Alright, now it's all clear to me! Thanks!